# Generic method to return string by operating on two different types

Tags: c#, generics

I have class like below :

```
public class SqlQueryObjContainer
    {
        public FilterClause Clause { get; set; }   
    }

  public class FilterClause
    {
        public List<WhereClause> WhereClauses { get; set; }
        public List<HavingClause> HavingClauses { get; set; }
    }

    public class WhereClause
    {
        public string Field { get; set; }
        public string Operator { get; set; }
    }
    public class HavingFilter 
    { 
        public string Field { get; set; }
        public string Operator { get; set; }
    }
```

This is my sql query which contains where and having clause like below :

```
select id,name from table where dbo.table.Column1 > 0 or dbo.table.Column2 > 0
group by id,name having  COUNT(id) < 4 AND COUNT(id) > 2
```

SO where clause contains records like this with 2 conditions :

```
[0] : Field = dbo.table.Column1 > 0
      Operator = null

[1] : Field = dbo.table.Column2 > 0
      Operator = or
```

Having clause will have records like below :

```
[0] : Field = COUNT(id) < 4
      Operator = null

[1] : Field = COUNT(id) > 2
      Operator = and
```

Below is my code to create where and having clause :

```
string query = "select * from table"
var i = 0;
if (sqlObj.Clause != null)
            {
                query = query + " where ";
                if (sqlObj.Clause.Whereclauses != null)
                {
                    foreach (var where in sqlObj.Clause.Whereclauses)
                    {
                        if(i > 0)
                        {
                            query = query + " " +  where.Operator + " ";
                        }
                        query = query + where.Field;
                        i++;
                    }
                }
            }

// above same repeated code for generating having clause
```

Above same code is repeated for having clause also because as you can see both where and having filters have records in same format so is it possible to create 1 generic method which will have this common logic inside 1 method and based on what i will pass(where or having clauses) it will return a string like below in case of where clause :

```
dbo.table.Column1 > 0 or dbo.table.Column2 > 0
```

I am thinking something like below but not getting :

```
private string CreateFilterClause<T>()
{
}
```

Comment: @john:Can you provide any sample code or reference from which i can get any idea and proceed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't wanna dig deep into what you are trying to achieve but you can add a base class or interface to your clauses.

```
interface IClause
{
    string Field { get; set; }
    string Operator { get; set; }
}

public class WhereClause : IClause
{
    public string Field { get; set; }
    public string Operator { get; set; }
}
public class HavingFilter : IClause
{
    public string Field { get; set; }
    public string Operator { get; set; }
}
```

And you can create a method like:

```
static string CreateFilterClause<IClause>(IClause param)
{
    string text = string.Empty;
    // you can now access the Field and Operator properties for param.

    return text;
}
```

And use this like:

```
string text = CreateFilterClause<WhereClause>(new WhereClause());
```

Comment: Upvoted for your kind efforts towards helping me and thank you so much for the answer and please keep helping like this :)